# Как в си сделать дескриптор сокета неблокирующим?

Tags: c, сокет, unix

Как в си сделать дескриптор клиентского и серверного сокетов неблокирующими?

Answer (score 2):

```
fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

Comment: есть ли принципиальные отличия от `ioctlsocket(fd, FIONBIO, &mode)`?

Comment: @Croessmah, это вызов из win на сколько я понимаю? со значением `mode!=0`, если не ошибаюсь, разницы в семантике нет, но разница может быть в поведении самих сокетов, тут надо читать документацию на конкретные системы...